# SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 in Ionic2 App

Tags: php, mysql, json, ionic2

I register the data to the database.Then I want to list the data but I get an error(SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0).I do not understand where I'm making mistakes.

**list.html**

```
<ion-header>

 <ion-navbar>
   <ion-title>list</ion-title>
 </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>

  <ion-list>
   <ion-item *ngFor="let isim of dataisim">{{isim}}</ion-item>
  </ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

**list.ts**

```
   import { Component } from '@angular/core';
   import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
   import {ServiceProvider} from "../../providers/datamember";
   import { Http, Headers, Response, ResponseOptions } from '@angular/http';

   @IonicPage()
   @Component({
   selector: 'page-list',
    templateUrl: 'list.html',
   })
   export class ListPage {


   dataisim : any;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: 
     NavParams,public service:ServiceProvider,
        public http : Http) {
       }

   ionViewDidLoad() {
     console.log('ionViewDidLoad ListPage');

       this.service.getList().subscribe(data =>
         this.dataisim = data );
          console.log(this.dataisim);
  }
 }
```

**service.ts**

```
  import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
  import { Http, Headers, Response, ResponseOptions } from '@angular/http';
  import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
  import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
  import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

  @Injectable()
   export class ServiceProvider {
     public local : Storage;
     mydata : any;
     api : string = 'http://localhost:8080/ionic2_kaydet.php';
     api2 : string = 'http://localhost:8080/kaydet3.php';
     url : string = "http://localhost:8080/listele.php";

     constructor(public http: Http) {       
    }
      postLogin(data){
      console.log("api data:" + data);
      let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-
       urlencoded' });
          return this.http.post(this.api, data, {
              headers:headers,
              method:"POST",                  
        }).map(
              (res:Response) => {return res.json();}
        );
     }

   getList() {

      let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-
     urlencoded' });
        return this.http.get(this.url, {
              headers:headers,
              method:"GET",                  
        }).map(
              (res:Response) => {return res.json();}
        )
    }

  }
```

**listele.php**

```
  <?php

  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

  $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "ionic2");
   $data= array();
   $select = "select * from user2";
   $qr = $conn->query($select);
    while($row = $qr->fetch_assoc()){
      $data[]=$row;
   }
  print json_encode($data);
 ?>
```

Comment: unexpected token usually means that the json is malformed, look into the Network tab (if you are using Chrome for instance)

Comment: What do you get if you run JUST the list.php in a browser?

Comment: Yes I use Chrome.The data comes.As if there is no hitch [{"id":"24","username":"onur","password":"3456"}]

Comment: @NigelRen [
  {
    "id": "24",
    "username": "onur",
    "password": "3456"
  }
]

Comment: Are you sure it's calling list.php? There doesn't seem to be a reference to this page in your other sources.

Comment: I am sure.I am using listele.php.list.php is wrong. my fault.I corrected the title :D

Comment: Could it be your request headers? 'Content-Type' : 'application/json'

Comment: header("Content-type:application/json");    
print json_encode($data);  I tried, but unfortunately